# Pandas pivot table - setting the months index as chronological order, not alphabetical

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, seaborn

I am trying to make a heatmap using seaborn, with months as the y-axis. However I see that if I call calendar.head() after making the pivot table, that the pivot table has the months column in alphabetical order instead of the chronological order which I have in my csv file. Is there anyway of stopping pandas from ordering it alphabetically, or to reorder it back to chronological order?

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/calendar.csv")

calendar = df.pivot("Month", "Year", "hPM2.5")

ax = sns.heatmap(calendar, annot=True, fmt="d")
```

Comment: Not sure right now which format you would use but you should cast the months to date objects first. As it stands pandas just sees strings and thus orders alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the months of the year stored in a list (in order) like so:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

And that these are the same strings used to represent months in your pivot table.

Then you can simply resort your pivot table by switching up its index using the correctly ordered `months` list like so:

```
calendar = calendar.reindex(months)
```

And your pivot table will now be ordered correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really needed this problem fixed and you just ended hours of torture for me.